# li element is not vertically aligning in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, navigation, height

In my navigation menu, I have the `li` set to 100% height so that the text is centered vertically in the menu. This works fine on Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc. but in IE it is not pulling this CSS. The `li` is only as tall as the text itself, so the menu elements are aligned to the top.

```
.nav li{height:100%}
```

I have looked into this and someone suggested that all parent containers must also have a height of 100% for it to work in IE, but they do.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

```
<nav role="navigation">
          <ul class="nav">
            {% for link in linklists.main-menu.links %}
            {% assign has_sub_menu = false %}
            {% assign has_sub_categories = false %}
            {% assign parent_link_active = false %}
            {% assign child_list_handle = link.title | handle %}
            {% if linklists[child_list_handle] and linklists[child_list_handle].links.size > 0 %}
              {% assign has_sub_menu = true %}
              {% for l in linklists[child_list_handle].links %}
                {% if page_title == l.title %}
                  {% assign parent_link_active = true %}
                {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
            {% elsif link.type == 'collection_link' and link.object.all_tags.size > 0 %}
              {% assign has_sub_categories = true %}
            {% endif %}
            <li class="nav-item{% if forloop.first %} first{% elsif forloop.last %} last{% endif %}{% if link.active or parent_link_active %} active{% endif %}{% if has_sub_menu or has_sub_categories %} has-dropdown{% endif %}">
              {{ link.title | link_to: link.url }}
              {% if has_sub_menu or has_sub_categories %}
              <ul class="sub-nav">
                <li class="sub-nav-niblet"></li>
                {% if has_sub_menu %}
                  {% for l in linklists[child_list_handle].links %}
                  <li class="sub-nav-item{% if forloop.first %} first{% elsif forloop.last %} last{% endif %}{% if l.active %} active{% endif %}">
                    <a class="{% if forloop.first %}first{% elsif forloop.last %}last{% endif %}" href="{{ l.url }}">{{ l.title }}</a>
                  </li>
                  {% endfor %}
                {% elsif has_sub_categories %}
                  {% for tag in link.object.all_tags %}
                  <li class="sub-nav-item{% if forloop.first %} first{% elsif forloop.last %} last{% endif %}{% if current_tags contains tag %} active{% endif %}">
                    <a class="{% if forloop.first %}first{% elsif forloop.last %}last{% endif %}" href="{{ link.url }}/{{ tag | handle }}">{{ tag }}</a>
                  </li>
                  {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
              </ul>
              {% endif %}
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

And the CSS:

```
nav {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    right: 0;
    float: none;
    margin-right: 210px;
}

.nav {
    display: table;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

    .nav li { 
        display: table;
        float: left;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        width: auto;
    }

        .nav li a {
            color: #eee;
            display: table-cell;
            font-size: 18px;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0 30px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

            .nav li a:hover {
                color: #fff;
                background-color:#1d1a1c;
            }
```

Comment: A code sample would be helpful here.

Comment: Please post a code sample (HTML+CSS). In general, you style the A-tags, not the LI.

Comment: You should have  show the HTML and CSS to understand it easily

Comment: I have updated the initial post with the code. I am using Shopify for the website. Thanks!

Comment: You don't know the exact height? why 100%?

Comment: Because it's a responsive site, if I set the exact height of the li then it doesn't look right when the browser window is scaled.

Comment: ok but there must be an element to get relation with the 100% of the nav, is it browsers size?

Comment: Ya, I have height:100% set globally under body, html(this was a suggestion I found on SO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please try this on your code. Change in your CSS the property of your `.nav` from `display:table` to this

```
.nav {
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: Alright, that fixed the issue with li not being 100% height, but now the text is not centered within the block and is floating to the top.

Comment: It was because I changed .nav li display to block as well. Changed it back to table and only changed .nav to display:block and now it is working. Thanks!